# nightmarejs document.getElementsByClassName() return empty object

Tags: javascript, dom, nightmare

I'm trying to grab the question titles from Stackoverflow home page. 
My nightmareJS code below.

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var startingLink = "http://stackoverflow.com"

var nightmare = Nightmare({show:true});

nightmare 
    .goto(startingLink)
    .evaluate(function() {
        return document.getElementsByClassName('question-hyperlink')
    })
    .end()
    .then(function(content) {
        console.log(content);
    })
```

It works when I run in Chrome console.

[image: Results Chrome Console]

However, in nightmareJS this is my output.

```
ming_o01 (master) nightmare1 $ DEBUG=nightmare node stackoverflow.js
  '48': {},
  '49': {},
  '50': {},
  '51': {},
  '52': {},
  '53': {},
  '54': {},
  '55': {},
  '56': {},
  '57': {},
  '58': {},
  '59': {},
  '60': {},
  '61': {},
  '62': {},
  '63': {},
  '64': {},
  '65': {},
  '66': {},
  '67': {},
  '68': {},
  '69': {},
  '70': {},
  '71': {},
  '72': {},
  '73': {},
  '74': {},
  '75': {},
  '76': {},
  '77': {},
  '78': {},
  '79': {},
  '80': {},
  '81': {},
  '82': {},
  '83': {},
  '84': {},
  '85': {},
  '86': {},
  '87': {},
  '88': {},
  '89': {},
  '90': {},
  '91': {},
  '92': {},
  '93': {},
  '94': {},
  '95': {} }
ming_o01 (master) nightmare1 $
```

Appreciate advise on why my objects are empty. See image for screenshot of HTML and Chrome console with results.

Comment: Anonymous downvoter care to explain why you downvoted??

Answer (score 2):

(Note: this conversation is a port from [segmentio/nightmare#617](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/issues/617).)

I suspect that DOMElement's parts are non-enumerable, and as such not crossing the IPC boundary.  In other words, it's not going to serialize well.

Fixing it is fairly straightforward: pluck the values you want inside of `.evaluate()`.  Say you wanted the question title and link:

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var startingLink = "http://stackoverflow.com"

var nightmare = Nightmare({
  show: true
});

nightmare
  .goto(startingLink)
  .evaluate(function() {
    var elements = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('question-hyperlink'));
    return elements.map(function(element) {
      return {
        href: element.href,
        title: element.innerText
      }
    });
  })
  .end()
  .then(function(content) {
    console.log(content);
  })
```

Note that the use of `Array.from` is deliberate: `document.getElementsByClassName()` returns a array-like object known as an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection).